# How to C#dim7 & half-diminished chord

Tags: chords

[image: The table for guidance]

I find this guide really useful until I find it kinda weird and "wrong" to apply it on key like  C sharp half-dimished or diminished chords. I find that I have to double-flat C natural to get the Bb for a C#dim7 , or just single-flat the C natural to get a B nat for a C#half-diminished chord. Just to make sure, a C#half-diminished chord consists of note c#, e, g, and b, right? I am very confused , I might have left out something but this is a main issue for me, is it because of the key with its tonic on the black keys?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem started when you thought the 7th note (leading note) in C# major is C. It can't be C, as that would have two different notes with the same C name, to be written on the C line or space on the stave.

That leading note is actually B#. Although enharmonic to C, its name here is B#. As in every note of the C# scale is the same as the C scale, but sharpened.

C# diminished then becomes spelled as C# E, G, Bb. The Bb being a tone lower that B#. C# half diminished then becomes C#, E, G, Bnat. The Bnat. being one semitone lower than the leading note, B#.

Other names are available for the dim. chord itself, but the spelling is here for C#o.

Comment: @DavidBowling - well spotted ! And with a 50/50... Almost worth a downvote! Someone missed the opportunity...I daresay not you, you're above that.

Comment: I knew the leading tone is B, but thinking of the Bb and B notes, I thought I had to make C the "replacing leading tone" to get a Bb and B. That's my problem. That's why I found it weird at first, I was confused so I asked.

Comment: Yes, except the leading note in C# Is **B#**, rather than B.

Comment: @Tim -- I was certain that it was a mere typo... otherwise, I would have offered you a last cigarette ;)

Comment: @Tim -- I'm sorry for the misunderstanding. I was thinking of C# minor

Comment: Leading note in C# major *and C# minor is still **B#**.

Comment: Do you mean raising the 7th pitch,B , like in harmonic minor scale? Because I was thinking of a C# natural minor scale

Comment: Yes, because unless that 7th note in the natural minor scale *is* raised (as in harmonic min.) it can't be a 'leading note'.

Comment: Ya, because that's the 'leading tone' ,and leading tone fuctions like that. Thanks for the reminder I slipped my mind

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have made a mistake somewhere.

C diminished 7th is C Eb Gb Bbb.

C# diminished 7th has all the notes one semitone higher: C# E G Bb

C half diminished 7th is C Eb Gb Bb.

C# half diminished 7th is C# E G B

Note that there are only three different diminished 7th chords (at least, in equal-temperament tuning) and each one can be "spelled" in different ways. The following are all the same notes:

C Eb Gb Bbb

Eb Gb Bbb Dbb

D# F# A C

Gb Bbb Dbb Fbb

F# A C Eb

Starting on Bbb doesn't work in practice, because you need a "triple flat" for the 7th:

Bbb Dbb Fbb Abbb

But starting on A works OK, of course:

A C Eb Gb

These alternative spellings "explain" why diminished 7th chords are very useful for modulating quickly between almost any pair of keys.

Comment: And so Major keys are made to be the basis, and then looking at whether the chords are minor, 7th (or any added notes of the chord), diminished or half-diminished, and other additional notations to the chord. Am I right to have this concept?

Comment: "You seem to have made a mistake somewhere." -- I am not sure what mistake you are referring to; OP spelled **C♯∅** correctly as C♯ E G B. The business about flatting and double-flatting "the C natural" to get a B or B♭ doesn't make sense, maybe that is what you are talking about?

Comment: @DavidBowling "maybe that is what you are talking about" - yes, that's what *I* was talking about.